# Use JPA query methods to seach records for specific day (day and month)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to implement a search operation for a restful API on a databases with records of movies with release dates. The format of the database is something like this:

```
title              running time    language    release date      
                   
Traffic shop       104             en          12/15/1995
Nocturnal men      101             en          12/22/1995
Exit front         127             en          12/22/1996
The last paradise  106             en          02/10/1995
```

, i need to get all movies released during lets say "12/22", so it needs to return:

```
Nocturnal men      101             en          12/22/1995
Exit front         127             en          12/22/1996
```

, even if they have been released in two different years. I'm not sure if this can be done using query methods in JPA but i'm still learning.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `day()` and `month()` function to extract data from date to compare

```
@Query("SELECT m from Movie m WHERE day(m.releaseDate) = ?1 and month(m.releaseDate) = ?2")
List<Movie> getMovieByDayAndMonth(int day, int month);
```